# ng-change not working on a text input

Tags: angularjs, colors, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

I am new to angular js. In my code there is color picker initialized from a text field. User changes the value of color and I want that color to be reflected as a background of a text in a span. It is not working. What is missing?

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="">
   <input type="button" value="set color" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
   <input type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myStyle={}">
   <input type="text" name="abc" class="color" ng-change="myStyle={color:'green'}">
   <br/>
   <span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
   <pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
</body>
```

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/APrl9Y98Em0d6rxuzRDE?p=preview

However when I change it to `ng-click` it works.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

ng-change requires ng-model,

```
<input type="text" name="abc" class="color" ng-model="someName" ng-change="myStyle={color:'green'}">
```

Comment: how can we use the value in the color picker as the style color?

Comment: One thing that the answer does not mention is the fact that the order actually matters, you NEED to set the ng-model before the ng-change to see this working.

Comment: @user1336321, it works in any order in current angular (not sure about 1.0 or something). There is no order rule for directives - there is priority... Who on Earth put +1 on this comment...

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same issue, my model is binding from another form, I've added `ng-change` and `ng-model` and it still doesn't work:

```
<input type="hidden" id="pdf-url" class="form-control" ng-model="pdfUrl"/>

<ng-dropzone
  dropzone="dropzone"
  dropzone-config="dropzoneButtonCfg"
  model="pdfUrl">
</ng-dropzone>
```

An input `#pdf-url` gets data from dropzone (two ways binding), however, `ng-change` doesn't work in this case. `$scope.$watch` is a solution for me:

```
$scope.$watch('pdfUrl', function updatePdfUrl(newPdfUrl, oldPdfUrl) {
  if (newPdfUrl !== oldPdfUrl) {
    // It's updated - Do something you want here.
  }
});
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

One can also bind a function with `ng-change` event listener, if they need to run a bit more complex logic.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">      
        <input type='text' ng-model='name' ng-change='change()'>
        <br/> <span>changed {{counter}} times </span>
 </div>
```

...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Australia';
      $scope.counter = 0;
      $scope.change = function() {
        $scope.counter++;
      };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/as0nyre3/1/

Answer (score 2):

When you want to edit something in Angular you need to insert an ngModel in your html

try this in your sample:

```
    <input type="text" name="abc" class="color" ng-model="myStyle.color">
```

You don't need to watch the change at all!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try something like this:

Using a directive

```
directive('watchChange', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            onchange: '&watchChange'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('input', function() {
                scope.onchange();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H2EAB/

Comment: this is handy if you want an ng-change like event but don't want an ng-model in an element

Answer (score 1):

First at all i'm seing your code and you haven't any controller. So i suggest that you use a controller.
I think you have to use a controller because your variable `{{myStyle}}` isn't compile because the 2 curly brace are visible and they shouldn't.

Second you have to use ng-model for your input, this directive will bind the value of the input to your variable.

Comment: My code is just a sample code to elaborate the problem. Actually in real it is very complex and I have used controller. Anyways thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Ok so you have just to bind an ng-model to your input