# AngularJS ng-change not working

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I mostly used ng-change but this time ng-change won't trigger It has also ng-model and also it is inside my app and controller. Same syntax for what I use in other ng-change. I got 3 days debugging this but still i cannot find the solution.

Here is the input:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-change="search()" ng-model="count_time">
```

Here is the controller:

```
var app = angular.module("myCurriform", []);


    app.controller("standardCtrl", function($scope,$http,$filter,$location,$window) {


      $scope.search = function() {
        console.log($scope.count_time);



      };


    });
```

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: none. no errors. my console is clean as white

Comment: post your whole html file

Comment: Can't post because i have too many lines of codes in my html file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-change not working on a text input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114974/ng-change-not-working-on-a-text-input)

Comment: add a plunker to debug your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following **the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models**

Comment: it's working for me, when I pasted this is a jsfiddle. No need for any modification at all.

Comment: I solve it when I transfer my script inside my .php. ng-change not working when it is only included but thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Use a watcher-function in your controller

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="count_time">
```

JS:

```
$scope.$watch('count_time', function() {
  $scope.search();
});
```

Comment: then create jsfiddle code to debug, because its working for me.